# Revel golang Request RemoteAddr always 127.0.0.1

Tags: go, revel

I just learning about Golang and Revel. And I have problem with the Request.RemoteAddr on the Revel which it always return 127.0.0.1:[port] even the requester is not localhost.
Which on godoc the RemoteAddr should the the IP of the requester.
Is it expected behaviour? If yes, how I can get the IP of the requester?
Another question also maybe you can help me, is it possible to get the os and mac address of the requester?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Have you tried getting the value of the `X-Forwarded-For` header?

Comment: No I don't use proxy. I test it with my local lan, accessed by other computer. Ah the X-Forwarded-For is the IP of the requester. But how come?